# $(document).ready shorthand

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready, shorthand

Is the following shorthand for `$(document).ready`?

```
(function($){

//some code

})(jQuery);
```

I see this pattern used a lot, but I'm unable to find any reference to it. If it is shorthand for `$(document).ready()`, is there any particular reason it might not work? In my tests it seems to always fire before the ready event.

Comment: Any variable defined inside the mentioned pattern function (e.g. `var somevar;`) will not change the contents of variables of the same name outside of the function

Comment: The code has the effect of ensuring $ represents jQuery within that function block so the code is portable to places where the $ alias for jQuery is disabled or defined as something else.

Answer (score 263, accepted):

The shorthand for `$(document).ready(handler)` is `$(handler)` (where `handler` is a function). See [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready).

The code in your question has nothing to do with `.ready()`. Rather, it is an immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE) with the jQuery object as its argument. Its purpose is to restrict the scope of at least the `$` variable to its own block so it doesn't cause conflicts. You typically see the pattern used by jQuery plugins to ensure that `$ == jQuery`.

Comment: *Technically* it's an **immediately invoked function expression**. Were it self-invoking, it would be calling itself from inside itself. Search the web for `iife`, or skip ahead to [Cowboy Alman's famous blog post](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). Details…sheesh.

Answer (score 590):

The shorthand is:

```
$(function() {
    // Code here
});
```

Comment: The first argument is `$`. Might want to add that in. It's useful for `jQuery(function($, undefined) {});`

Comment: @raynos Its not required.  the above code works fine as an alias for `$(document).ready(function(){ });`

Comment: It's just useful to know that you get `$` for free as the first argument.

Comment: I still visit this answer once a month or so.

Answer (score 94):

The correct shorthand is this:

```
$(function() {
    // this behaves as if within document.ready
});
```

---

The code you posted…

```
(function($){

//some code

})(jQuery);
```

…creates an anonymous function and executes it immediately with `jQuery` being passed in as the arg `$`. All it effectively does is take the code inside the function and execute it like normal, since `$` is already an alias for `jQuery`. :D

Comment: You could say that it also ensures that $ is the alias for jQuery, if other tools that also use $ as an alias are loaded

Answer (score 24):

Even shorter variant is to use

```
$(()=>{

});
```

where `$` stands for jQuery and `()=>{}` is so called ['arrow function'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that inherits `this` from the closure. (So that in `this` you'll probably have `window` instead of `document`.)

Answer (score 15):

This is not a shorthand for `$(document).ready()`.

The code you posted boxes the inside code and makes jQuery available as `$` without polluting the global namespace. This can be used when you want to use both prototype and jQuery on one page.

Documented here: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/#use-an-immediately-invoked-function-expression

Comment: Thank you for answering the question

Answer (score 13):

The multi-framework safe shorthand for ready is:

```
jQuery(function($, undefined) {
    // $ is guaranteed to be short for jQuery in this scope
    // undefined is provided because it could have been overwritten elsewhere
});
```

This is because jQuery isn't the only framework that uses the `$` and `undefined` variables

Comment: also can be written as `(function($){ ... })(jQuery);`

Comment: @MikeCauser also a good approach, but it will not be called on `ready`, instead it's called immediately

Answer (score 11):

These specific lines are the usual wrapper for jQuery plugins:

"...to make sure that your plugin doesn't collide with other libraries that might use the dollar sign, it's a best practice to pass jQuery to a self executing function (closure) that maps it to the dollar sign so it can't be overwritten by another library in the scope of its execution."

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    // Do your awesome plugin stuff here
  };
})( jQuery );
```

From http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
(function($) { 
   $(function() {
     // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
     // will be fired when document is ready
   });
})(jQuery);
```