# Change image on time does not work (can't find whats causing it)

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I want to make slideshow in wordpress, but for some reason it doesn't work:

my .js file:

```
(function ($) {
    function slideSwitch() {
        var $active = $('#gallery1 IMG.active');

        if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#gallery1 IMG:last');

        var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
                : $('#gallery1 IMG:first');

        $active.addClass('last-active');

        $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
    }

    $(function() {
        setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
    });

});
```

CSS styles:

```
#gallery1{
    position: relative;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
}
#gallery1 img{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:8;
}
#gallery1 img.active{
    z-index:10;
}
#gallery1 img.last-active{
    z-index:9;
}
```

html code:

```
 <div id="gallery1">
 <img src="img1.jpg" class="active"/>
 <img src="img2.jpg"/>
 <img src="img3.jpg"/>
  </div>
```

Chromes developer tools doesn't show any errors. While firebug, shows this error:
error breakpoints:

But I don't get it what's wrong with first image, it loads fine.
Does anyone see the problem?

Comment: You may want to verify that your first line is doing what you think it's doing.  I don't know where you have this script block defined but if it's in the head or before your images that you've defined then the DOM may not be loaded.  Try using the $(document).ready shorthand version which is $(function () {  [Here is a previous question on jQuery $(document).ready shorthand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004129/document-ready-shorthand)

Comment: Can you create an example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: There could be a problem with scopes here, you are extending the JQuery object in a way that I am not sure is supported in ths position.

Comment: Infact I am pretty sure if you use: `(function ($) {` you must end with `})(JQuery);` and the function doesn't actually run on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the answer provided solved my problem (don't know why that person deleted his answer):
This one worked:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

function slideSwitch() {
var $active = $j('#gallery1 IMG.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $j('#gallery1 IMG:last');

var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $j('#gallery1 IMG:first');

$active.addClass('last-active');

$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
.addClass('active')
.animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
    $active.removeClass('active last-active');
});
```

}

```
$j(function() {
setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@nez is correct in that your function will not be executed when the DOM is ready because of how you declare your anonymous function.  It should look like this:

```
(function ($) { 
    function slideSwitch() {
        var $active = $('#gallery1 IMG.active');

        if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#gallery1 IMG:last');

        var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
                : $('#gallery1 IMG:first');

        $active.addClass('last-active');

        $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
    }

    $(function() {
        setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
    });
}(jQuery));
```

This declaration is helpful to make sure that your plugin doesn't collide with other libraries that might use the dollar sign, it's a best practice to pass jQuery to an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) that maps it to the dollar sign so it can't be overwritten by another library in the scope of its execution.  Straight from their documenation:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: Are you still receiving an error when your referencing the dollar sign?

Comment: No, when I use this, I don't get any error, but images do not change. The answer that I written (that person deleted it) is working.

Comment: Sorry, actually it's working. Did you edited? I tried it before, and images didn't change. So both approaches work. Thanks for solution.

Comment: Haha ok because I was thinking that all I am doing is aliasing jQuery to $ inside the scope of the annonymous function.  I did not modify the code.  I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I checked again and I think last time my browser wasn't refreshed (so it used the other solution), so I thought it is working, but it seems to not be working. So gave best answer for Sammaye

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong.

You need a no conflict version of JQuery which will run along side prototype by aliasing it as shown in this link: http://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/

Then make your code:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $j('#gallery1 IMG.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $j('#gallery1 IMG:last');

    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
            : $j('#gallery1 IMG:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}

$j(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out what might be going wrong with your code, however, here is an alternative to create a slideshow that uses the [SlidesJS](http://slidesjs.com/) jquery plugin.

```js
$("#slides").slides({
    preload: true,        
    play: 2000,
    pause: 2500        
});
```

See it in action **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ajorpheus/VGQJ4/2/)**  (The above code is towards the bottom in the Javascript editor)

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you never executed the first function (that's why you see an image and nothing happens).

Try:

```
$(function() {

  var slideSwitch = function () {
    var $active = $('#gallery1 IMG.active'),
      $next;

    if ($active.length == 0) {
      $active = $('#gallery1 IMG:last');
    }

    $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $('#gallery1 IMG:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
      .addClass('active')
      .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
      });
  }

  setInterval(slideSwitch, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Maybe you didn't see, but I'm using this function in wordpress, and wordpress do not allow to use $ in jquery. So I have to bypass it.
I tried what you suggested and got this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function .
I was getting this error before I changed function as it is now.

Comment: @oerp first result on Google provides the right code: http://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/

Comment: Well I tried this one: http://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/
to be able to use $. Forgot to add (jQuery) at the end, but it doesn't solve it.

Comment: @oerp If you've made changes to your code based on answers provided it's usually a good idea to update the question to reflect that.

Comment: @oerp Are you sure Jquery is actually being loaded into your widget?

Comment: @oerp Please mark the answer that you used if your problem was solved.