# Wrong compiling coffeescript with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, coffeescript

I have this simple coffescript

```
$(document)
   .ready -> $('body') .css -> 'background-color':'black'
```

it's compile to

```
(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    return $('body').css(function() {
      return {
        'background-color': 'black'
      };
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

after that i have some console error `no method 'replace'`, what is wrong? Much thx for help.

Comment: It looks like you are using jQuery incorrectly - what are you trying to do?

Comment: The shorthand for `$(document).ready ->` for jQuery is just `$ ->` - see http://api.jquery.com/ready/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004129/document-ready-shorthand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your CS to

```
$(document)
   .ready -> $('body') .css 'background-color':'black'
```

So that the argument passed to `css` is `{'background-color': 'black'}` instead of a function.