# Javascript Age verification Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I creating a age verification popup by helping few online tutorial & on e of my friend due to my low knowledge on JavaScript.

Check live- http://www.arif-khan.net/project/popup/

My problem is i want to load/appear this popup after loading page content but don't know how to do it.

Code-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function confirmAge(){
var d = new Date();
//var time_stmp = Math.round(d.getTime()/1000);
var now_us = d.getTime();


var myDate=document.getElementById('day').value +"-"+ document.getElementById('mon').value +"-"+ document.getElementById('yer').value;
myDate=myDate.split("-");
var newDate=myDate[1]+"/"+myDate[0]+"/"+myDate[2];
var date_us=new Date(newDate).getTime();

var age_us=(now_us-date_us)/(1000*356*24*3600);


if(age_us<18){
    alert("You must be 18 years of age to see this site.");
    return false;
}
else
    document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display="none"; 

   }
</script>
```

CSS-

```
<style>
#ac-wrapper {
position            : absolute;
top                 : 0;
left                : 0;
width               : 100%;
height              : 820px;
background: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
z-index             : 1001;
}
#popup{
 width: 555px;
height: 375px;
background: #FFFFFF;
border: 5px solid #000;
border-radius: 25px;
-moz-border-radius: 25px;
-webkit-border-radius: 25px;
 box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
-moz-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
-webkit-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
position: relative;
top: 150px; left: 375px;
 }
 #popup_logo{
position: relative;
left: 130px; top: 30px;
 }
 #popup_form{
text-align: center;
 }
 #popup_submit{
width: 120px;
height: 47px;
background: url(images/Enter-button.png) no-repeat;
cursor: pointer;
border: 0px;
 }
 p{
font: bold 20px Tahoma;
color: #000;
text-align: center;
 }
</style>
```

HTML-

```
    <div id="ac-wrapper">
      <div id="popup"> <img src="images/store_logo.png" alt="D elicious Liquid Vapor" id="popup_logo"><br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <p>To play with the bull, you must be 21 years of age.<br />
          Please enter your birth date...</p>
        <br />
        <div id="popup_form">
          <select name="birthmonth" id='mon'>
            <option value="1">January</option>
            ......................
            <option value="12">December</option>
          </select>
          <select name="birthday" id='day'>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            .....................
            <option value="31">31</option>
          </select>
          <select name="birthyear" id="yer">
            <option value="2007">2013</option>
            ..............
            <option value="1900">1900</option>
          </select>
          <br />
          <br />
          <input type="button" id="popup_submit" name="submit" value="" onClick="confirmAge()" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That is a *lot* of HTML. Consider trimming it down so we have an easier time helping you.

Comment: Is the linked demo safe-for-work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do an asynchronous callback (to a function that renders your popup) after the content has loaded - either when the DOM is ready or when all content is loaded ( which may well be too long)

Have a look here

http://javascript.info/tutorial/onload-ondomcontentloaded

You're code will need to be restructured slightly something like

```
function renderMyPopup() {
 // implementation in here 
}
```

then the asynchronous callback here

```
onload = function() {
    renderMyPopup()
}
```

... there are easier ways of doing this if you use jQuery 
see here

[$(document).ready shorthand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004129/document-ready-shorthand)