# onClick add input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a transparent input text field in the centre of DIV `#mainC` each time the button is clicked.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NathaliaZeed/6nkd5/1/)

I tried doing this with jquery but did not succeed.

Comment: you talking about a placeholder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$("#abc").click(function() {
    $("#main").append('<input type="text" />');
});
```

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6nkd5/5/**

Answer (score 0):

Well there's multiple things wrong with your code:

- You use the same ID multiple times (ID's can only be used once, classes can be used multiple times).
- Calling a function from a external JavaScript source will result in the function not running.
- You're trying to use jQuery when jQuery is not loaded
- `$('<input type="aText" id="aText">').appendTo('#main')` is not a valid jQuery, instead try to use: `$('#main').append('<input type="text" id="aText">');`
- `aText` is not a valid input type attribute value

Comment: Why is `$('<input ...>').appendTo('#main')` invalid? When `$()` takes HTML as an argument, it creates a DOM element and returns a jQuery wrapper for that element, which has the method `appendTo`. So what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

There is no library selected at the upper left corner in jsfiddle. Try to select jquery there.

Comment: will that add a transparent input text filed in the centre of DIV `#mainC`?

Comment: No but it is neccessary for using jquery functions.

Comment: yes, we know. but the problem reported is not in the jsfiddle, it's in the code. does the jsfiddle work now that you have enabled jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Use `append()` and try not to specify `onclick` inline. You can register the event with jQuery [when document is ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004129/document-ready-shorthand). Registering methods this way is preferred because you separate logic from your HTML (Check [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)).

This is how you would do it preferably:

```
$('#abc').on('click', function(){
    $('#mainC').append('<input type="aText" id="aText">')
})
```

Check also [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nkd5/14/)

The problem you had with your jsFiddle was also that no jQuery script was selected.