# jQuery append - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery

I am just struggling beyond belief with jQuery. I have looked at dozens of ways of adding a new `input` field but keep getting stuck right at the beginning. I don't see how this could be simpler.

```
<div class="container">
<p>If you click on me, I will disappexxxxxxar.</p>
<p id="thisone">Click this onexxxx me away!</p>
<p id="thixxsone2">Click 2pppp22222hover me too!</p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
</div>

 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> window.jQuery||document.write("<script src='../vendor/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js'><\/script>")</script>
<script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../custom/js/custom.js"></script>

<script>
$("#chk").on("change",function(){
        $("#chk").append('<input type="text" />');
    }
)
</script>
```

I will be adding a `if ($("#chk").is(":checked"))` which seems to work fine.

I went through W3 jQuery but it was too short. Anyone know of another online "course"?

Comment: OK sorry guys have tried solutions but not working on my simple page. I need to clean it right out and start again. Thanks for efforts will report back.

Comment: The W3 - so far as I know - offer no jQuery 'course,' you may have referred to 'w3schools" which has no connection to the W3C *at all*, though they deliberately named themselves to imply a connection. If you want to learn about jQuery you'd be best off looking to the jQuery docs: [API.jQuery.com](http://api.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of an old StackOverflow question([onClick add input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25067435/onclick-add-input-field)), I wrote an example that uses jquery append and works:

**Html**

```
<button id="add">Add input field</button><p id="main"></p>
```

**js**

```
$('#add').on('click', function () {
$('#main').append('<input type="aText" id="aText"><br>');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uhhr60pj/
Hope that helps.

Comment: Yep thanks worked great. Now all I have do is about another 20 clever things on top of this. Cannot work out why I am so slow at jQuery.

Comment: Don't worry, it just takes practice. You asked for a more online jQuery help, here's a list of jQuery courses and tutorials: http://www.tutset.com/frontend/jquery/

Answer (score 0):

1st: what this line expect to do??

```
<script> window.jQuery||document.write("<script src='../vendor/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js'><\/script>")</script>
```

2nd: good to wrap your code after document ready .. and you can use .append for your input parent() .. this will append new input after checkbox input

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#chk").on("change",function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $(this).parent().append('<input type="text" />');
    }     
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Mohamed thanks it was not working on my page but you had a fiddle up and that worked fine QED something wrong with my page. Have to leave for about an hour then will clean up page. Please stand by and thanks. Shukran

Comment: Regarding your question to the OP, "*[that] line*" will simply write a script element into the document if `window.jQuery` is a false/falsey value. It's a hideous practice, but I think that's the intent of it.

Comment: Mohamed can't get it to do anything sorry. As to the line yep found it as a check on access to google jQuery. David why is it horrible. Absolutely non essential - just curious.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks .. I just seeing he included jquery in a right way from ajax.googleapis.com  cause of that I asked .. I thought that line can make conflicts with the main jquery  .and I didn't use that line before in any of my projects . but  I will read about this :)

Comment: @OldMauiMan never mind, Just you reached the answer you need .. and that's it .. Good Luck :)

Comment: Thanks. But as I want something to appear when the box is checked - that is my next step -I may be back.... You have been warned.

Answer (score 0):

You have one main problem with your code in your question:

```
$("#chk").on("change",function(){
  $("#chk").append('<input type="text" />');
});
```

The problem is that an `<input>` is a void element:

> A void element is an element whose content model never allows it to have contents under any circumstances. Void elements can have attributes.
>
> The following is a complete list of the void elements in HTML:
>
> area, base, br, col, command, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr

<sub>Citation: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements, accessed 01:00, 2015-11-23.</sub>

Because jQuery – almost always – fails silently it never alerts you to the fact that you're trying to achieve the impossible (literally: the impossible); so instead you have to append the elements elsewhere, such as *after* (or before) the given element.

```js
// bind the anonymous function of the
// on() method to handle the change
// event of the '#chk' element:
$('#chk').on('change', function() {

  // on the assumption you only want
  // to append elements when the element
  // is in fact checked:
  if (this.checked) {

    // creating the <input> element:
    $('<input />', {

      // setting its 'type' attribute/property:
      'type': 'text',

      // setting its 'placeholder' attribute:
      'placeholder': 'input number: ' + $('input[type=text]').length

      // inserting the <input> after the '#chk' element:
    }).insertAfter(this);
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <!-- I removed the irrelevant HTML -->
  <label>Click to add a new input element (when checked):
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
  </label>
</div>
```

As you can see when you check the check-box this appends the new `<input>` directly after that check-box. Since I don't expect that's what you want to do, I'd suggest amending the above, to access the parent – `<div>` – element:

```js
// bind the anonymous function of the
// on() method to handle the change
// event of the '#chk' element:
$('#chk').on('change', function() {

  // on the assumption you only want
  // to append elements when the element
  // is in fact checked:
  if (this.checked) {

    // creating the <input> element:
    $('<input />', {

      // setting its 'type' attribute/property:
      'type': 'text',

      // setting its 'placeholder' attribute:
      'placeholder' : 'input number: ' + $('input[type=text]').length

    // appending the <input> element to the parentNode of the
    // '#chk' element:
    }).appendTo(this.parentNode);
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <!-- I removed the irrelevant HTML -->
  <label>Click to add a new input element (when checked):
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
  </label>
</div>
```

References:

- jQuery:

  - [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
  - [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: David wow. This was just a two line code check. I will look at this later as my head is exploding. I DID however expect the input to come directly after the checkbox - this was just a tiny incremental test. (If I don't understand something I build it up in tiny ugly steps!) As to the `input` being a void element - yes I was aware of that. I did NOT realize that would be a problem (not sure why) but in any case Katie's solution worked fine. (So???)  I am however extremely grateful for your full answer. Some of your code will be very helpful when I build up the next layer of  ugly complexity.