# Name of this jQuery Pattern?

Tags: jquery, design-patterns

What's the name of this pattern please?

I'm planning to research it after finding out its name... however, if you like you are welcome to explain what it does.

```
(function($) {


      //code


            })(jQuery);
```

Comment: This question has your answer, friend!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004129/document-ready-shorthand

Comment: $(function() { ... }); is document ready shorthand... OP's question is the immediately invoked function expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Immediately Invoked Function Expression](http://stage.learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/functions/#immediately-invoked-function-expression-iife) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the self-executing anonymous function?

i.e. http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/

Comment: Also known as [**Immediately-Invoked Functions Expressions**](http://stage.learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/functions/)