# Can't hide the SCM Music Player on Tumblr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to hide the annoying SCM Music Player and expand the main container to 100% (since the player reduces it a little bit on the bottom) on my Tumblr blog but my code doesn't work.

The JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').contents().find('iframe').contents().find('#contentW').css({top: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px;});
    $('body').contents().find('iframe').contents().find('#playerW').css({display: none;})
});
```

The loaded page structure (note that I omitted some unnecessary code):

```
<html>
    <head>
        // some Tumblr content
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe> // unnecessary iframe generated by SCM
            <html>
                <head>
                    // some SCM content
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div id="contentW" style="top: 0px; bottom: 25px; right: 0px;">
                        // THE BLOG MAIN CONTAINER IS HERE
                    </div>
                    <div id="playerW" style="top: auto; bottom: 0px; height: 25px;">
                        // AND THE ANNOYING PLAYER IS HERE
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Sidenote: instead of using a `setTimeout` to wait for the page's load use [the proper way of doing it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6004179/2629998) with document.ready.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I changed it on my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it with no JS/JQuery, just creating a CSS file, uploading it as a static file to Tumblr and using the link as a custom skin on the SCM website.

Here's the CSS code:

```
#playerW {display: none !important;}
#contentW {top: 0 !important; bottom: 0 !important; right: 0 !important;}
```