# Hide SCM player in tumblr

Tags: css, tumblr

I need an extra help with this, i'm just learning to code, already found [this preview question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476567/cant-hide-the-scm-music-player-on-tumblr) but i don't understand completly how the css file must be done and upload. Or if any other way to do the same.

This is [my page](https://liquidacolectiva.tumblr.com/) and this is the code that SCM provides

```
!-- SCM Music Player http://scmplayer.net -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.scmplayer.net/script.js" 
data-config="{'skin':'skins/black/skin.css','volume':50,'autoplay':true,'shuffle':false,'repeat':1,'placement':'top','showplaylist':false,'playlist':[{'title':'blalbla','url':'test'}]}" ></script>
<!-- SCM Music Player script end -->
```

What I want to do it's hide it and delete the extra space that gives to the bottom.

Comment: There should be a style tag in the head of the template. Most css is added there (this is the best way to do it). Some themes also load external css files. If this is the case in your template you have to override any css you don't want. Either adding css code after the files are called and/or increasing specificity in your css. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Either way you need to post some code and/or a link to your theme, or no one can help you.

Comment: Thank you, I edit the question with link and code, in the old question that I already link they've done what I'm trying to do but i don't completly understand how.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like

```
#playerW {
  display: none!important
}
```

I don't like using `!important` because it's usually a sign of poor code, but here I think it's required as the css properties for the scm player are being set by javascript. The other method might be:

```
html body iframe #playerW {
   display: none;
}
```

This adds more specificity to the target element. You want to load this after the `scm.css` link in your template.

However I would also check that these things are not already configurable within your theme.

Based on your last comment (and looking at the current implementation of your theme) I have this hack

```
#scmframe {
    display: block;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: fixed;
    top: -30px; // change this from 0px
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120%; //change this from 100%
    z-index: 1667;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this method in different ways but it's still not working, I've even tried uploading a custom skin with display:none but doesn't work. As a temporal fix I put transparent background but it looks weird

Comment: Do you mean the border at the top?

Comment: If so I have a hack and I have added this to my answer.