# Wordpress jQuery: Selecting div's with no specific class or id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have spent way to much time on this and now I need help (days in fact). The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class='five mobile-four columns'>
        <label class='right inline'>
          Ciudad/Estado
        </label>
      </div>
</div>
```

The code is as follows:

```
(function ($) {
    $('div:contains("Ciudad/Estado")').css('display', 'none');
    $("#field_2762").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Seleccione') {
            $("div:contains('Ciudad/Estado')").css('display', 'none');
        }
        if ($(this).val() == 'Puerto Rico') {
            $("div:contains('Ciudad/Estado')").css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
});
```

Basically I want the select the parent div with a very common .row class so I can hide it and show it dependent on a dropdown. So far the variations of code I have tried (in the thousands) have not worked.

I am new to StackExchange so please feel free to be kind.

Comment: (function ($) { -> should be '$(function(){' -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004129/document-ready-shorthand Change it, and code will work, i guess...

Comment: @nevermind Thanks for the quick response but no effect on the changes. Any other ideas?

Comment: Code is working - not sure what is problem. http://jsfiddle.net/1wnn4naL/ Did you included jquery?

Comment: @nevermind I also had used jsfiddle and worked perfectly. Yes jQuery is included and started. No errors on Firefox or Chrome.