# Can't call external javascript function from JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script file called `trim.js`. I'm trying to call a function `prepareURL()` from this file in my index.html file. However I'm getting the following error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: prepareURL

I make sure to import my script doing the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/trim.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
    $('#simple_sketch').sketch();
    $('#simple_sketch').sketch('color','#fff');
    $('#simple_sketch').sketch('size','6');         
  });

  function predict() {
    //Create Image URL
    var imageURL = prepareURL('#simple_sketch')
  }
```

The function in my trim.js file looks like this:

```
function prepareURL(c) {
  //My code
}
```

How can I call prepareURL from my index.html file?

Comment: Try adding like this - `prepareURL = function(c) {  }` in trim.js

Comment: Something is missing here. All of the code you posted should work as intended. When/where are you calling `predict()`? Are the contents of trim.js contained in an IIFE?

Comment: wrap your script in $(document).ready

Comment: @user3791775 OP's using shorthand http://stackoverflow.com/a/6004143/5812121

Comment: Does the same error occur if you include contents of `trim.js` as text within `<script></script>` element ?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? having the same issue