# Fetch data with Vue from Web API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Web API and I'm trying to get JSON Data from it by using Vue, but I get neither data or errors, so I don't what is wrong. I want to load the data when the page is loaded.

Here is my code:

```
const v = new Vue({
    el: '#divContent',
    ready: function () {
        this.loadData();
    },
    data: {
        content: 'loading',
        serverData: null
    },
    methods: {
        loadData: function (viewerUserId, posterUserId) {
            const that = this;
            $.ajax({
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "http://my-webapi/",
                method: "Post",
                success: function (response) {                        
                    that.$data.serverData = response;

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error')
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

My HTML

```
<div id="divContent" class="content">
 {{ content }}
</div>
```

Comment: why u don't work with axios for ur http request ? it's easy to use then ajax

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih if someone is already using jQuery why would they use axios, it will add only bloat.

Comment: I don't know about Vue that much, I'm a newbie

Comment: @DakshMiglani for the best practice and maintainable code

Comment: In Vue 2, there is no `ready` lifecycle handler. That went away and was replaced with `mounted`. In Vue 2, for situations like this, you would use either `created` or `mounted`.

Comment: Do you see the network request being made at all in the network panel of devtools?

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can use jQuery’s $.ajax() API. However, using jQuery just for making Ajax calls is not recommended. You don’t want to include the whole jQuery library just for the purpose of using Ajax, do you? :-)

For Vue.js, you have quite a few options for using Ajax, such as:

- [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)
- [vue-resource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource)
- [Browser's built-in fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) ([Using fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch))

Here is [an example of using the Browser's fetch API](https://jsbin.com/muzamos/edit?html,js,output).

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
  <div id="divContent">
    <h1>Article Search Results</h1>
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="search">
      <input type="text" v-model="query">
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>

    <ul>
    <li v-for="article in articles" v-bind:key="article.source + article.id">
      {{ article.title }}
    </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### JavaScript

```
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#divContent',
  data() {
    return {
      query: 'gene',
      articles: 'loading'
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.search();
  },
  methods: {
    search: function () {
      fetch(`https://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search?query=${this.query}&format=json`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          this.articles = json.resultList.result;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

#### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You appear to already be using jQuery, so to load the Vue when the **page** is loaded you can update your code to the following:

```
$(function(){
  const v = new Vue({
    el: '#divContent',
    created: function () {
      this.loadData();
    },
    data: {
      content: 'loading',
      serverData: null
    },
    methods: {
      loadData: function (viewerUserId, posterUserId) {
        const that = this;
        $.ajax({
          contentType: "application/json",
          dataType: "json",
          url: "http://my-webapi/",
          method: "Post",
          success: response => this.serverData = response,
          error: err => alert('Error')
        });
      }
    }
  });  
})
```

The syntax above is using the [`jQuery.ready` shorthand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6004143/38065) to create the Vue only after the page is loaded.

Without jQuery, you might want to listen for the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event.

Alternatively, just load the script that creates the Vue at the *bottom* of the page and not in the header.

Here is a complete, working example.

```js
console.clear()

$(function(){
  const v = new Vue({
    el: '#divContent',
    created: function () {
      this.loadData();
    },
    data: {
      content: 'loading',
      serverData: null
    },
    methods: {
      loadData: function (viewerUserId, posterUserId) {
        $.ajax({
          contentType: "application/json",
          dataType: "json",
          url: "https://httpbin.org/post",
          data: JSON.stringify({testing: "some value"}),
          method: "Post",
          success: response => {
            this.content = "loaded"
            this.serverData = response.json
          },
          error: err => console.log('Error')
        });
      }
    }
  });  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>
<div id="divContent" class="content">
  {{ content }}
  <hr>
  Response: <br>
  {{ serverData }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything your put inside `methods: {}` won't work
unless you call `loadData()` with  @click on the element or when page loads.

So, you should call it on the element or using either created/mount methods:

So, in your case either do this.

```
<div id="divContent" class="content" @click='loadData'>
```

or call the method when the page loads as:

```
created () {
 this.loadData()
}
```

Comment: I want to load the data when the page loaded

Comment: @DainaHodges then add the `created() {}` after your `methods: {}`

Answer (score 0):

For Loading it on the page load, you can do the following:

```
const v = new Vue({
    el: '#divContent',
    data: {
        content: 'loading',
        serverData: null
    },
    methods: {
        loadData(viewerUserId, posterUserId) {
            $.ajax({
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "http://my-webapi/",
                method: "POST",
                success: function (response) { 
                    this.content = 'loaded';                       
                    this.serverData = response;

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error')
                }
            });
        }
    },
    mounted() {
       this.loadData()
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried it but nothing happened, no result, no errors

Comment: @DainaHodges check now, but you should know that you have to update content property to view changes.

Comment: Not working :(
Is there any working example where I can learn from it?

Comment: You have an issue with `this`.

Comment: @bert what? can you elaborate?

Comment: `this.serverData = response` will not work because you define the callback using `function(){}`.

Comment: @DainaHodges try now :)

Comment: The ajax function jumps to the line after
 mounted() {
                this.loadData()